# java: calling value of a variable in one class from an implemented class of interface

Tags: java, class, interface

I have a class A in java that sets a value in variable alpha. The class A calls a function of an interface "MessageListener" as below:

```
private List<MessageListener> mListeners;

for (MessageListener ml : this.mListeners) 
{
ml.messageTransferred(aMessage, from, this.host, isFirstDelivery);
}
```

I want to pass alpha to the messageTransferred function of MessageStatsReport.java class that implements the above mentioned interface.

If I modify the arguments of messageTransferred function this affects 12 other classes from the same interface (MessageListener). So what is the easy way out? How can I call a (non-static) variable value that was set in class A. Any help please?

Comment: is A a MessageListener or does A use a function that uses an array of MessageListener?

Comment: yes, A use a function that uses an array of MessageListener to call functions of classes that implement messageListener

Comment: the class where above code is written is itself an abstract class: public abstract class MessageRouter {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array of messageListeners is called by A then how is any MessageListener supposed to 'know' about alpha? A called method can not access properties or methods of the callee inside of it since the type of the callee may change. You have to pass alpha around if you want A to be aware of it.

Notice that you are changing the **contract** that MessageListener defines by having it deal with another parameter, if it were possible to breach the interface's contract without anyone knowing about it, well that wouldn't make any sense (in java's perspective, some languages do allow this).

You are passing a message, shouldn't alpha be a part of that message? in what format is aMessage?

One solution is to define an interface that defines that what an actual message transfered looks like. In a simplified way, you can have a `message` interface and have a `SimpleMessage` and `ComplicatedMessage` that implement it. aMessage can be of that type and you can handle the contents based on what the interface defined.

Comment: this is exactly what i started doing before receiving your reply, passing alpha through a message property. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

make method next

```
messageTransferred(aMessage, from, this.host, isFirstDelivery, alpha)  
{   
   if (alpha != null)  
   {
   // ...  
}
```

and now, when you want pass alfpha to method, use

```
messageTransferred(aMessage, from, this.host, isFirstDelivery, alpha);
```

and when you don't want use alpha, pass `null` instead of alpha

```
messageTransferred(aMessage, from, this.host, isFirstDelivery, null);
```